# WooCommerce how to pass ID's to billing-form input fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a `WooCommerce` shop and on checkout I have a specific checkout form layout. When I click the order button, I get an alert that the fields must be filled out, even though I filled them out. 
I found out, that I don't get the ID's of the input fields due to my customization, but I'm not sure how to get these ID's:

here is my code so far:

```
<?php
    $fields = $checkout->get_checkout_fields( 'billing' ); ?>

        <div class="checkout-input-group">
            <div class="input-wrapper"><?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $fields['billing_first_name'] );?></div>
            <div class="input-wrapper"><?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $fields['billing_email'] );?></div>              
        </div>
        <div class="checkout-input-group">
            <div class="input-wrapper"><?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $fields['billing_last_name'] );?></div>
            <div class="input-wrapper"><?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $fields['billing_phone'] );?></div>              
        </div>              
        <div class="checkout-input-group">
            <div class="flex-group left">
                <div class="input-wrapper first"><?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $fields['billing_address_1'] );?></div>
                <div class="input-wrapper second"><?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $fields['billing_address_3'] );?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-group right">
                <div class="input-wrapper"><?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $fields['billing_delivery'] );?></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="checkout-input-group">
            <div class="input-wrapper"><?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $fields['billing_postcode'] );?></div>
            <div class="input-wrapper"><?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $fields['billing_child_name'] );?></div>
        </div>
        <div class="checkout-input-group">
            <div class="input-wrapper"><?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $fields['billing_city'] );?></div>
            <div class="input-wrapper"><?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $fields['billing_childs_grade'] );?></div>
        </div>              

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', $checkout ); 
 ?>
```

Ok, from this point of view its clear that I dont get ID's of the fields. The default code for the billing-form loop is this:

```
foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
    woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );
}
```

but I dont know how to use that to build my layout.

So, how can I pass the IDs to my layout e.g input fields?

Comment: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) and also available filters in [woocommerce_form_field()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#2066-2278)